# how to Prepar/Use docker executor/pull docker image openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66?

Tags: docker, openfoam

I am trying to pull and run docker image openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66 as follows:

1. I have used this main Command

```
docker container run -ti cfdengine/openfoam
```

2. The name of openfoamplus (1612+) by using the following command to get the name

```
docker search openfoam
openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66
```

3. Then I used upper main Command with the name of openfoam plus as follows

```
docker container run -ti cfdengine/openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66
```

4. it gives me always this error (Error)

```
$ Unable to find image 'cfdengine/openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/cfdengine/openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66/manifests/latest": unknown: invalid repository name.
```

5. When I am using the main Command it gives no errors and I could be in foam

```
docker container run -ti cfdengine/openfoam
whoami ------ > foam
openfoam6 (not openfoamplus 1612+)
```

6. When I use the following command, it shows that openfoamplus 1612+ image is already existing

```
dockerimages

REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
cfdengine/openfoam                   latest    4b64701b18ec   4 years ago   1.33GB
openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66   latest    5fce8f6a8a79   6 years ago   2.17GB
```

I have tried another way to pull this version of openfoam as in GitHub but did not work also. I am totally new with openfoam.
I am using Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS und want to compile with openfoam plus 1612+.
Any suggestion or direction would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the container as follows:

```
docker run -it openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66 /bin/bash
```

Within the container, change the directory to:

```
cd /opt/OpenFOAM/
```

source the script: `setImage_v1612+` by running:

```
source setImage_v1612+
```

Now you should be able to use `OpenFOAM-v1612+`, in other words you can run OpenFOAM solvers/utilies, e.g:

```
simpleFoam
```

Comment: Thank you . getting the following :                                                                    'docker run -it openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66 /bin/bash'
'[root@8ba75954a3f0 /]# '                                                                                                             next Command :                                                                                                'cd /opt/OpenFOAM/'
getting
'$ [root@8ba75954a3f0 OpenFOAM]#'
Then
'source setImage_v1612+'
as follow:
'$ [root@8ba75954a3f0 OpenFOAM]# '
should i be able to use OpenFOAM -v1612+ ?

Comment: Thnks i have this error as follow :
--> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR: 
cannot find file

file: /opt/OpenFOAM/system/controlDict at line 0.

    From function regIOobject::readStream()
    in file db/regIOobject/regIOobjectRead.C at line 237.

FOAM exiting