# Getting such error by using command simpleFoam --> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR: cannot find file

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, openfoam

I am trying install Openfoam v1612+ and i have used following steps from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176616/5920411):

running the container

```
docker run -it openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66 /bin/bash
```

Within the container, changing the directory to:

```
cd /opt/OpenFOAM/
```

source the script: setImage_v1612+ by running:

```
source setImage_v1612+
```

when using the command

```
simpleFoam
```

I am getting the following Error as follow and in the screenshot also:

```
--> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR: 
cannot find file

file: /opt/OpenFOAM/system/controlDict at line 0.

    From function regIOobject::readStream()
    in file db/regIOobject/regIOobjectRead.C at line 237.

FOAM exiting
```

[image]

As i understood that this file /opt/OpenFOAM/system/controlDict not excisting and i do not how to solve this or what is this file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the solver on a case that has already been configured.

For example, you can run a tutorial on that docker container by following these steps:

- `cd` to a tutorial, e.g:

```
cd $FOAM_TUTORIALS/incompressible/simpleFoam/airFoil2D
```

- When listing the contents of the current directory (using `ls` command), you should see the typical OpenFOAM case setup, which includes the necessary folders and files such as `0`, `constant`, `system`, and any additional files specific to your case.
- You can then run the solver which is in this case `simpleFoam`:

```
simpleFoam
```