# Creating Docker Container for usage of Openfoam v1612+

Tags: docker, containers, openfoam

I want to be able to use openfoam v1612+ in docker Container. I am using Ubuntu. I am hoping for any Help and if there is any better more organized way.

I will write all the steps that i have done so far by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176616/5920411) and the error that i am getting.

1. Pulling by the command

```
docker pull openfoamplus/openfoamplus1612:latest
```

2. then running the docker container as follow ( without /bin/bash is giving me always error)

```
 docker run -it openfoamplus/of_v1612plus_centos66 /bin/bash
```

3. Create a new case directory inside the container:

```
 mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN/<case-name>
```

4. Copy the necessary files for case into the new case directory.
5. Within the container, changing the directory to:

```
cd /opt/OpenFOAM/
```

6. source the script: setImage_v1612+ by running:

```
source setImage_v1612+
```

7. Navigate to the case directory and run the compilation command:

```
cd $FOAM_RUN/<case-name>
```

8. Using the Command `wmake` and the files `muVisc.C` and `muVisc.H` are already existing.
   But getting always this Error:

```
> wmakeLnInclude: linking include files to ./lnInclude
make: *** No rule to make target `Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/muVisc/muVisc.C.dep', needed by `Make/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/muVisc/muVisc.o'.  Stop.
```